# Broadcast receiver shows activity in background to incoming call screen in sony xperia 4.0.4

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call

My `Broadcast` receiver opens activity by getting incoming call it ok with *samsung mobile* but on *sony xperia 4.0.4* activity comes like a splash screen and systems incoming call screen comes over my activity when i disconnect the call my activity comes again for long time.

How do i resolve this problem?

I have started an `Activity` with following flags.

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

When a call is came. Calling screen activity started and come to foreground. So Please use thread sleep for 2 to 3 seconds and start your activity.

It will shown foreground to calling screen.